# How to get configurable product price?

Tags: magento-1.9, price, invoice, pdf

For product I have configurable attributes.
I want to get price of that product.
Price, Special price and final price.

I want to show this in invoice pdf.

I used

```
getPrice()
getSpecialPrice()
getFinalPrice()
```

to get price. But I am not getting price for configurable attributes.
Hope you understand.
[image: Image showing costume attributes that changes the price]

Comment: configurable attributes ?? please clarify it

Comment: Please share the code you are using.